# Checking if element is in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I got this code:

```
grades = [2, 3, 4, 5]

assignments = 5


x = [int(input('Ocena z cwiczenia {}: '.format(i+1))) for i in range(assignments)]
if x(input) in grades:
print("ok")
else:
print("no ok")
```

And as you can see I've written the list with possible grades that can be written by user so my code can check if they are entered correctly. I wanted it to show an error if entered number is not on the list "grades". The error that I get is:

```
File "C:\Users\Wojtek\Desktop\untitled2.py", line 19, in <module>
if x(input) in grades:

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I guess there is something wrong with the order of lines. The "x" is going to be entered by user and what I wanted is to show an information that the entered grade does not exist (in my country, grades at universities vary from 2 to 5 only).

Comment: x is a list and you should check for each entry in x if it exists in grades.

Answer (score 0):

you must check every element in your `x`. `x` is a list. Look at my example below:

```
grades = [2, 3, 4, 5]

assignments = 5


x = [int(input('Ocena z cwiczenia {}: '.format(i+1))) for i in range(assignments)]
for element in x:
    if element in grades:
        print("ok")
    else:
        print(f"{element} is not ok")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is this:

```
grades = [2, 3, 4, 5]
assignments = 5
x = [int(input('Ocena z cwiczenia {}: '.format(i+1))) for i in range(assignments)]

if all([[True if i in grades else False for i in x]]):
    print('ok')
else:
    print('not ok')
```